# Erlang List Creation

Tags: list, erlang

Why is the following 2 expressions that can create a list return different results in Erlang?

```
> ["A" | []]
// returns ["A"]
> [[] | "A"]
// returns [[], 65]
```

I was expecting that the second expression returns the same result as the first one. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To properly understand how this works, keep in mind that all these expressions follow this pattern:

```
[head | tail]
```

where `head` is a single element and tail is another list.

Also note that strings are list of characters, that is, `"A"` is actually equal to `[65]`.

Hence, in the first case, a list whose head is `"A"` and whose tail is `[]` is created and that turns, as expected, into `["A"]`.

However, in the second case, the head is `[]` and the tail is `"A"`, which is equal to `[65]`. Therefore, the result is the head element (`[]`) plus all the elements in the tail (`65`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why they should be the same. You might be thinking that `[A|B]` concatenates lists `A` and `B`, but it doesn't: it's meant to prepend the *element* `A` to the *list* `B`.

`["A" | []]` is an ordered pair that has `"A"` as its first element and `[]` as its second, which corresponds to the list with `"A"` as its single element.

`[[] | "A"]` is an ordered pair with `[]` as its first element and `"A"` as its second; since a string is actually a list of ASCII codes in Erlang, that means it's the same as the list containing `[]` and `65` (ASCII `A`) as its elements. Because the first element of the list is itself a list, this is a nested list.